# Codes that are both locally testable and locally decodable

Tags: coding-theory

Are there any known constructions of binary [locally testable codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_testable_code) with very low (e.g., independent of the length of the codeword) query complexity and "good" rate (e.g., mapping strings of length $k$ to strings of length $k^{1+c}$, for a small constant $c$) that are also [locally decodable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_decodable_code) (even if the query complexity for decoding is very large (but still sublinear))?